UI not able to receive confirmation or decline response from AWS Lex
My React app is not able to capture  confirmation or decline response from AWS Lex
const handleSendMessage = async () => {
        const params = {
            botId: BOT_ID,
            botAliasId: BOT_ALIAS_ID,
            localeId: LOCALE_ID,
            text: message,
            sessionId: `user${Date.now()}`
        };

        try {
            const command = new RecognizeTextCommand(params);
            const data = await lexClient.send(command);
            if (data.messages && data.messages.length > 0) {
                setResponse((prevResponse) => `${prevResponse}\n${data.messages?.[0].content}`);
                enable5GHz();
            } else {
                setResponse((prevResponse) => `${prevResponse}\nNo response from bot.`);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            setResponse((prevResponse) => `${prevResponse}\n;Error occurred while communicating with Lex`);
        }
    };

I am receiving the Confirmation prompt "Do you want to proceed" after I write the utterance but after writing yes/no no further messages are received and the data value received is
{
    "dialogAction": {
        "type": "Close"
    },
    "intent": {
        "confirmationState": "None",
        "name": "FallbackIntent",
        "slots": {},
        "state": "ReadyForFulfillment"
    },
    "originatingRequestId": "6775bd4f-96b3-42b6-96f8-eb37b90448c4",
    "sessionAttributes": {}
} 

But the Lex inbuilt tester is working as expected
